# Where is the proof that the Beast’s parents were the KING and QUEEN?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast-2017

This question is strictly for the live-action remake only, so the animated version is out of the question.

Anyway, their wiki articles calls the Beast’s parents the King and Queen, but nothing in the film supports that. Mrs. Potts simply calls his father “the master’s father.”

We should also take into account that the Beast was still a Prince in the prologue, not a King, and he wasn’t 11 in this version.

So, for all we know, they could be the previous Prince and Princess of a Principality in France.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the end credits. King and Queen.

[image: Screenshot of the end credits; gold writing on a blue background; some amazingly drawn freehand red arrows point to the names of the "Queen" played by "Harriet Janes" and the "King" played by "Tom Turner"]

Also, repeatedly mentioned in the film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30145679-beauty-and-the-beast-novelization).

> Her breath caught in her throat as Belle realized that they reminded her of the Beast’s eyes. Mrs. Potts’s words came back to her. A prince of a fellow, she had said. This must have been the prince she was referring to. She glanced again at the portrait, looking for clues to the past. **There were two other people in the portrait—a handsome king and beautiful queen.**

Comment: Well, then, why did the Prologue call the Prince a PRINCE? Was his father still alive or what? If he died, surely Adam would’ve been the next King?

Comment: He hadn't reached his majority yet, or perhaps he was just too busy carousing to be bothered with a boring coronation.